# Why can't I break out of this do while loop in java?

Tags: loops

Even though the input I type is a "Y" or "N" string, I can't break out if this while loop. Can anyone tell me why?

```
public String yesOrNo(String message) {
    String yesOrNo;

    do {
        System.out.print(message);
        yesOrNo = input.next(); 
    } while(yesOrNo != "N" || yesOrNo != "Y");
    
    return yesOrNo;
}
```

Comment: If yesorno is N then the second condition is true. If it is Y then the first condition is true. If neither then both conditions are true. The OR is always true. You want AND. Plus of course != or == compares pointers, and the pointers will never be equal.

Comment: @gnasher729, I would be careful with "the pointers will never be equal". It's not unreasonable to imagine a JVM implementation that uses singletons for single-character strings.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments by gnasher729, you have made a mistake in your logic.

Your logic is as follows:

| Input | A: Input != "N" | B: Input != "Y" | A∨B (OR) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Y | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE |
| N | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE |
| *Anything Else* | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |

The logic you want:

| Input | A: Input != "N" | B: Input != "Y" | A∧B (AND) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Y | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| N | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| *Anything Else* | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |

---

In your code change or OR to be an AND to match the logic expressed above:

```java
while(yesOrNo != "N" && yesOrNo != "Y");
```